# How to check if single.php has already called the_post_thumbnail function

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, actions, the-content

I am creating a front end plugin to upload images and adding filter in `the_content()` to display post thumbnail but some templates already have `the_post_thumbnail` in `single.php` or `loop.php`. Is there any way I can check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several hooks in `get_the_post_thumbnail` for example

- `begin_fetch_post_thumbnail_html`
- `end_fetch_post_thumbnail_html`

[`/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php)

You could add a function to one of these actions which removes your filter on first run.

If you need further help with this please add some code how you filter `the_content`.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Problem solved..
`add_action('end_fetch_post_thumbnail_html','thumbnailexist');
function thumbnailexist(){
remove_filter('the_content', 'my_postthumbanil_content_filter');    
}`